# Need help understanding how the below IIFE code works

Tags: javascript, iife

I recently came across this javascript code in a competitive site and couldn't understand how this pretty much works.

```
var a= 1;
(function(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 2;
    console.log(a);
})();
```

I expected the output to be..

> 1 2

But to my surprise, the original output was..

> undefined
>   2

Can someone please explain how it works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is localization, I believe. The function creates a new "Global" scope that's localized.

Comment: This is an extraordinarily common example. Surely there is plenty of explanation online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of variable `a` is brought to the top of the scope. This process is called hoisting.

```
var a= 1;
(function(){
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a = 2;
    console.log(a);
})();
```

Consider a general snippet without a IIFE and global variable.

```js
function func(){
  console.log(x)
  var x = 2;
  console.log(x)
}
func()
```

The declaration of `x` is hoisted to the top of the scope of the function.So the above code is same as

```
function func(){
  var x; //x is declared and its value is undefined
  console.log(x)
  x = 2;
  console.log(x)
}
func()
```